# Input type Radio checked not work if open in new window

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, window.open

My planing is click on button in link.html page (exp: Check option 2 in radio.html),
it will go to radio.html page and checked the option 2 radio.

I can checked the radio by click on button in radio.html page.

But if click button on link.html, i can't checked the radio when open the radio.html page.

I get a idea is use `windows.open` to open the radio.html, then use `window.onload` & `document.getElementById` to checked the radio.

But failed. Is my idea wrong?

Please help, TQVM.


Here is the radio.html code:

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="option"  id="opt1">  
<label for="opt1">Option 1</label> 
<input type="radio" name="option"  id="opt2">        
<label for="opt1">Option 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="option"  id="opt3">        
<label for="opt1">Option 3</label>
<input type="radio" name="option"  id="opt4">        
<label for="opt1">Option 4</label>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="check1()">Check Option 1</button>
<br>
<button onclick="check2()">Check Option 2</button>
<br>
<button onclick="check3()">Check Option 3</button>
<br>
<button onclick="check4()">Check Option 4</button>
<br>

<script>
function check1() {
    document.getElementById("opt1").checked = true;
}
function check2() {
    document.getElementById("opt2").checked = true;
}
function check3() {
    document.getElementById("opt3").checked = true;
}
function check4() {
    document.getElementById("opt4").checked = true;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the link.html code:

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="opencheck2()">Check Option 2 in radio.html</button>
<br>
<button onclick="opencheck3()">Check Option 3 in radio.html</button>
<br>

<script>
function opencheck2() {
 var mywindow = window.open("radio.html","_self");
 mywindow.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("opt2").checked = true;   
 }
}
function opencheck3() {
 var mywindow = window.open("radio.html","_self");
 mywindow.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("opt3").checked = true;   
 }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `mywindow.document.getElementById`? I believe that just saying document will refer to the current window's document.

Comment: I already try put `mywindow.document.getElementById("opt3").checked = true; ` in `mywindow.onload = function()`, but still can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this seems to be to add an event listener to the window that you are opening so that when it loads then the code can be triggered. Here's an example that will open this current SO page and replace the content with the word `test` (you would have to run this from the console as code snippets seem unable to open new windows):

```
var mywindow = window.open(document.URL);
mywindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
  mywindow.document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'TEST';
});
```

Here's a modified version of your code that takes advantage of the same behaviour. I've also reduced it into one function where the buttons now pass a number representing the checkbox to be ticked rather than having multiple functions:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="opencheck(2)">Check Option 2 in radio.html</button>
<br>
<button onclick="opencheck(3)">Check Option 3 in radio.html</button>
<br>

<script>
function opencheck(num) {
  var mywindow = window.open("radio.html");
  mywindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
    mywindow.document.getElementById("opt" + num).checked = true;           
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried, but it no open the radio.html after i add `addEventListener`. But it give me an idea. i try do some research on it. thanks.

Comment: i success get it by open the "radio.html" in new window or new tab, it working fine, without addEventListener. code is: `var mywindow = window.open("radio.html", "mywindow1");
   mywindow.document.getElementById("opt" + 3).checked = true;           
}` But i hope open in same window, any idea?

Comment: What you're describing is a redirect. The problem is that as soon as you load a new page then all code execution stops, which doesn't allow you to do what you want this way. The simplest method would be to pass a query parameter in the URL and then use that to modify what is checked or not, but that might require some extra research on your part.

Comment: sorry for late reply. Thx for ur comment, i understand what your mean.